# Extract list of texts with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs, text-extraction, html-content-extraction

I want to extract the text values out of this List:

```
<ul class="standardSuggestions">
    <li class="">

        <div id="idac">
            <span class="email" id="idb7"><span>mail-fuer-chrisko</span>@<span>web.de</span></span>
            <span class="btn-positioner"><span class="btn-wrapper btn-fix btn-service btn-xs"><input name="wishnamePanel:suggestionsContainerWrapper:freeMailSuggestionsPanel:standard-suggestion-list:suggestionRepeaterContainer:suggestion-to-repeat:1:suggestion:subForm:select-email" id="idae" value="Übernehmen" type="submit"></span></span>
        </div>

    </li><li class="">

        <div id="idaf">
            <span class="email" id="idb8"><span>post-fuer-chrisko</span>@<span>web.de</span></span>
            <span class="btn-positioner"><span class="btn-wrapper btn-fix btn-service btn-xs"><input name="wishnamePanel:suggestionsContainerWrapper:freeMailSuggestionsPanel:standard-suggestion-list:suggestionRepeaterContainer:suggestion-to-repeat:2:suggestion:subForm:select-email" id="idb0" value="Übernehmen" type="submit"></span></span>
        </div>

    </li><li class="">

        <div id="idb1">
            <span class="email" id="idb9"><span>chrisko1</span>@<span>web.de</span></span>
            <span class="btn-positioner"><span class="btn-wrapper btn-fix btn-service btn-xs"><input name="wishnamePanel:suggestionsContainerWrapper:freeMailSuggestionsPanel:standard-suggestion-list:suggestionRepeaterContainer:suggestion-to-repeat:3:suggestion:subForm:select-email" id="idb2" value="Übernehmen" type="submit"></span></span>
        </div>

    </li><li class="">

        <div id="idb3">
            <span class="email" id="idba"><span>chrisko.1</span>@<span>web.de</span></span>
            <span class="btn-positioner"><span class="btn-wrapper btn-fix btn-service btn-xs"><input name="wishnamePanel:suggestionsContainerWrapper:freeMailSuggestionsPanel:standard-suggestion-list:suggestionRepeaterContainer:suggestion-to-repeat:4:suggestion:subForm:select-email" id="idb4" value="Übernehmen" type="submit"></span></span>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is that the div id = "" is changing on every reload. So I'm not sure how to select correct elements. I tried it with the following function:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
        return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
            return {
                text: node.querySelector("span").textContent
            };
        });
    });
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(listItems, undefined, 4)); 
});
```

echo is "null" :-(

Comment: Are you sure that `node.querySelector("span")` is always available? If not then this will lead to an error, because there is no `textContent` property on `undefined`.

Comment: hmm... jep. Tried it a few times. <span> is always available.

Comment: Ok, have you tried simply `text: node.textContent`?

Comment: this scrapes too much.. part of the output is:      "text": "\n            Dieser Wunschname ist leider schon vergeben\n        "
    },
    {
        "text": "\n            \n    \n        chrisko.70@web.de\n        \n    \n\n        "
    },
    {
        "text": "\n            \n    \n        chrisko_70@web.de\n        \n    \n\n        "
    },
    {
        "text": "\n            \n    \n        mail-fuer-chrisko@web.de\n        \n    \n\n        "
    },
    {
        "text": "\n            \n    \n        post-fuer-chrisko@web.de\n        \n    \n\n        "
    },

Comment: The first entry looks different than the others. If you inspect the page, there is probably another `<ul>` which doesn't contain any `<span>` elements.

Comment: jep on the page is another <ul> correct. How can i catch the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration over the elements is correct. The only way to get a `null` value out of the page context is if there was an error. The only part of the code that can produce an error is `node.querySelector("span").textContent`, because a `node` doesn't necessarily have to have a `<span>` descendant. If it doesn't have one, then this fails with a TypeError and you get `null`.

The limited markup that you've shown always contains a `<span>` in every `<li>`, so there must be another `<ul>` on the page, that has no `<span>` descendants. You have to find a CSS selector with doesn't include the other `<ul>` element.

I propose

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('ul.standardSuggestions > li');
```

Comment: Phantastic! Now i have the correct Selection, but the output is not as excpected :-( [
    {
        "text": "\n            \n    \n        chrisko.70@web.de\n        \n    \n\n        ".. How can i get the "chrisko.70@web.de" and the other extract in an array?

Comment: `node.querySelector("span").textContent.trim()` should do it, since the outer stuff is just whitespace

Comment: Unfortunately not only Whitespace. After Trim output is: [
    {
        "text": "mail-fuer-chrisko@web.de"
    },
    {
        "text": "post-fuer-chrisko@web.de"
    },
    {
        "text": "chrisko1@web.de"
    },
    {
        "text": "chrisko.1@web.de"
    }
]

Comment: i excpected, like in PHP: listitems[0]=mail-fuer-chrisko@web.de, listitems[1]=post-fuer-chrisko@web.de and so on. if i do console.log(listItems) or echo (listitems) i just get [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]

Comment: It seems you don't want the texts wrapped in an object. Maybe `return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) { return node.querySelector("span").textContent.trim() });` is what you're looking for.

Comment: No, I don't want to wrap the Text in Objects. Better for my case is an exklusive String for every value or an Array with the seperate text values. return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) { return node.querySelector("span").textContent.trim() }); is the same than above

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your issue.

Comment: The Problem is how to get the [object Object] echo on the console to a mail-fuer-chrisko@web.de output. At the End i need the mail-fuer-chrisko@web.de in a string variable. Not in an nodelist object.

Comment: Since you have access to the data, you can build a string in any way. You can iterate over the list and concatenate the texts in a way that you need.

Comment: Got it... easy ;-) this.echo (listItems[1].text); Many thanks to you!